# Is it ok to inject both UnitOfWork and DbContext itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unit-of-work

I am using **UnitOfWork** pattern and it's working perfectly
but as I need to use UserManager and SinginManager
I have to add this part to **startup.cs** as well

```
        services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(
            @"Data Source="));
```

but since I'm using **UnitOfWork** I add these line too;

```
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork<MainDbContext>, UnitOfWork<MainDbContext>>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork<FinancialDbContext>, UnitOfWork<FinancialDbContext>>();
```

> Is it OK to inject and active both ways in **startup.cs**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two registrations appear to be related.

The first

```
services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=Main...."));
```

makes the container aware of how to resolve the context itself when requested,

while the second registers types that most likely depend on the context

```
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork<MainDbContext>, UnitOfWork<MainDbContext>>();
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork<FinancialDbContext>, UnitOfWork<FinancialDbContext>>();
```

The above can also be simplified using open generics to

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>), typeof(UnitOfWork<>));
```

which tells the container

> *"When ever `IUnitOfWork<SomeContext>` is request, resolve to `UnitOfWork<SomeContext>`"*

So there is nothing wrong if you require units that use different contexts

```
services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=Main....")); 
services.AddDbContext<FinancialDbContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=Financial...."));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>), typeof(UnitOfWork<>));
```

With that out of the way, do note that the Entity Framework is already designed around the Unit of Work / Repository pattern with its `DbContext` and `DbSet` respectively.

Comment: so it ok to use both?  base on your answer shoul i add both? like this?
services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=Main...."));

services.AddDbContext<FinancialDbContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=Financial...."));

Comment: @keyone2693 there is nothing wrong with that if you require units that use different contexts

Comment: so what do you mean by ?
With that out of the way, do note that the Entity Framework is already designed around the Unit of Work / Repository pattern with its DbContext and DbSet respectively.

Comment: @keyone2693 it is sometimes argued that the design you are using is redundant given that EF already follows the UoW pattern. I just wanted to bring that to your attention. I personally do the same as you did.

Comment: so U just saying that its too much unnecessary work? right? some people say it that way?

Comment: @keyone2693 Personally, I don't think so, but others disagree. There is a thin line between how this design can go wrong depending on how well it is designed to avoid leaky abstractions.

Comment: I'm going to just categorically say using the UoW/repository pattern around EF is wrong. I've yet to hear any good argument for it, aside from abstracting EF. However, 1) it doesn't do a good job of that, anyways, and 2) there's more appropriate patterns for that: CQRS, microservices, service layer, etc.